# CodeIgniter form helper will not send POST data to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeIgniter and PHP in general and I have a problem that i can not find the solution online. I have a registration form that when redirected to the controller my post data is not set, I have a done a test to see if it is set and it fails, whats more annoying is that my login form works as expected and the code is identical. My view is:

```
$attributes = array(
  'id' => 'formID',
  'class' => 'formClass'
);

echo form_open('user/register_validation/', $attributes);

echo validation_errors();

echo "<p>Username: ";
echo form_input('rusername');
echo "</p>";

echo "<p>Email: ";
echo form_input('remail', $this->input->post('remail'));
echo "</p>";

echo "<p>Password: ";
echo form_input('rpassword');
echo "</p>";

echo "<p>Confirm Password: ";
echo form_input('cpassword');
echo "</p>";

echo "<p>";
echo form_submit('register_submit', 'Register');
echo "</p>";

echo form_close();

?>
```

The controller method:

```
public function register_validation(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('remail', 'Remail', 'required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[userbee_db_table.email_user]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('rpassword', 'Rpassword', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Cpassword', 'required|trim|matches[rpassword]');

    $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'That email address    already exists.');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()){
        redirect('user/register_user');
    }else{
        $this->load->view('register_view');
    }
}
```

My controller has no constructor, and i am using WAMP3 virtual server. I know that the controller method redirects to another method but that is to load the model and insert the user, however no data is passed from the form to the first controller method, please help!

Comment: when your form validation run true then you have to load the model class then call a model function to insert your post data then you have to use redirect function. @redRyno

Comment: Thanks that did fix the problem but i do not understand why you need to load the model first for post data to be active, does the redirect function destroy post data? but agiain thanks

Comment: to use insertion function which define in model class so  we need to call model class. no interaction with post data.

Comment: You have to make insertion in same method where form validation is. Otherwise, beeing redirected it is another request and `$_POST` data is no  more provided. So solution is to move code from `user/register_user` to block where validation is passed.